# Firebase custom event parameters analysis on console

Tags: firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I cannot figure out how to view event parameters on the Firebase console. I have confirmed that the parameters are sent and received correctly: on the individual event page, I can view event parameters for the last 30 minutes:

[image]

---

The only guide/suggestion I found was to click on the overflow menu next to an event, then select "Edit Parameter Reporting" but I do not have this option:

[image]

How do I analyse the event parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add your [custom parameter for reporting](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304). However, it seems that Firebase recently deprecated this feature and replaced it with [custom dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209).

What's the difference between the two?

- With **custom-parameter reporting**, parameters were identified for individual events.
- With **custom dimensions and metrics**, parameters are identified for property-wide dimensions and metrics, so you can create a single dimension or metric based on a parameter and report on it for as many events as you like.

If you can't see the custom dimensions and metrics feature yet, maybe your project is still being migrated.

You should be able to see the button to create custom dimensions and metrics on Events page. The custom dimensions are your parameters with text value, while the custom metrics are your parameters with numeric value. After you register the parameters, it should be added on the events details page for succeeding data.

Comment: Can you please share how to create these dimensions and metrics? I can see this new feature on Google Analytics but "parameter" is no where to be seen. The closet I could find was "Event value" but that just shows 0 for all Event Names.

Comment: You should be able to see the button to create custom dimensions and metrics on Events page. The custom dimensions are your parameters with text value, while the custom metrics are your parameters with numeric value. After you register the parameters, it should be added on the events details page for succeeding data.

Comment: Great, thank you! If you add these instructions to your answer, I will give you a tick.